# the module u2lcom.dll was loaded but the entry point dllregisterserver was not found

Tags: crystal-reports, regsvr32

I am creating a crystal report which will use UFL, it work in my development machine, but when I put to testing machine, error and show u2lcom.dll is missing.

And then I checked u2lcom.dll is located in `C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\2.8\bin`, when I regsvr32, it prompt entry point not found.

And then I use Dependency Walker to trace and found IEFRAME.DLL has missing entry-point #160 #141 and #159, so how can I solve this problem

Comment: u2lcom is not COM dll and thereby regsvr32 is supposed to err out. Have you registered your UFL containing COM component on testing machine? Have you installed CR runtime properly?

Comment: I have tried to test on two machines and re-install the CR runtime, it doesn't work.  But on the other hand, it work on 2 development machine which was installed VS before, so I think it is caused by .net issue but I cannot locate which module is required to be re-install.